# What is the most compact syntax to return a string from Razor block?

Tags: razor, syntax, return-value

What is the shortest syntax for returning a string? Something that will cure a code like below (just an example, please don't "solve" this by saying -- use CSS classes):

```
<p style="@{ if (foo.isBar) { <text>font-weight:bolder</text> } }">...
```

*Probably my shortest question of all time.*

**Update:** Razor for MVC 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
<p style="@(foo.isBar ? "font-weight:bolder" : "")">
```

or

```
<p style="@(foo.isBar ? "font-weight:bolder" : "font-weight:bold" )">
```